# Testcontainers + dbrider: Could not clear table X, message:Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled., cause: null

Tags: java, spring-boot, dbunit, testcontainers

Having a simple Spring boot app, with following integration test configuration:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(ResourceUtils.CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX + "application-test.properties")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@DBRider
@DBUnit(caseInsensitiveStrategy = Orthography.LOWERCASE, qualifiedTableNames = true)
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {

  protected static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER; // shared among all test classes

  static {
    POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:9.5-alpine");
    POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER.start();
  }

  @Autowired
  protected MockMvc mockMvc;

  @DynamicPropertySource
  static void postgresqlProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("spring.datasource.url", POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER::getJdbcUrl);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.username", POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER::getUsername);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.password", POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER::getPassword);
  }

  @Test
  void contextLoads() {
    Assertions.assertThat(mockMvc).isNotNull();
    Assertions.assertThat(POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER.isRunning()).isTrue();
  }
}
```

```
public class UserControllerTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

  @Test
  @DataSet(value = {"/dbunit/users.yml"}, cleanBefore = true)
  void getUserTest() throws Exception {
   var resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get("/api/users/{id}", 1)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }

   // Other tests ommitted.
}
```

I get following warning messages:
`WARN  com.github.database.rider.core.dataset.DataSetExecutorImpl - Could not clear table user, message:Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled., cause: null`

The cause of the error is the fact that I specified dbunit should clean before.

I'm not sure what I should do to get rid of this warning and the funny thing is, the table is cleared, even though the warning says otherwise.

Comment: Did you get any solution?